# How to fix javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed Authentication failed exception in Java 7?

Tags: java, smtp, gmail

I am getting javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;

```
nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at com.wings.util.SendEmail.sendMail(SendEmail.java:81)
```

The application is built on Java 7. I tried another way after researching like somewhere written turned on allow less secure app. So I tried to search this option in GMail setting. Google has by default removed this feature recently. So I tried creating app password also. I used that password in my code. I don't know why I am getting this exception again.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at com.wings.util.SendEmail.sendMail(SendEmail.java:81)
        at org.apache.jsp.sendContact_jsp._jspService(sendContact_jsp.java:131)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error when sending Msg :: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

Comment: Pleased edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 2):

Google removed the option for less secure apps.

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

In order to authencate to the smtp server now you need to use an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) in replace for the users actual password.

```
final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "appspassword";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
```

another option would be to use xoauth2

Comment: @DalmTo If I generate app password, so is there any need to change gmail password with app password too?

Comment: Very good question!  The answer is No Leave your Gmail password what it is. Apps password is something on the side mainly used when someone has 2fa enabled to bypass it.   If you change your google password in the future this will still work as the apps password will still be the same.